# Reshape all the documents in the collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following structure in my documents:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "item" : {
        "name" : "abc",
        "price" : 10,
        "quantity" : 2,
        "date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T08:00:00Z")
    }
}
```

And I want to transform each document on this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "abc",
    "price" : 10,
    "quantity" : 2,
    "date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T08:00:00Z")
}
```

In other words remove the embedded document but not the details!

Thanks!

Comment: It means: update the collection to the following structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the  [`aggregation`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) especially the [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#project-aggregation)operator for that. The [`$out`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) operator let you write the result in another collection.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id", 
        "name": "$item.name",
        "price": "$item.price", 
        "quantity": "$item.quantity", 
        "date": "$item.date"}
    }, 
    { "$out": "collection"}
])
```

You documents now look like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "abc",
    "price" : 10,
    "quantity" : 2,
    "date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T08:00:00Z")
}
```

You can also **overwrite** the pre-existing collection by giving the new results collection the same name but this.