# Change document structure in mongodb with the mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a document structure in mongodb and i want to change it for all my documents without using aggregate function like this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580281/reshape-all-the-documents-in-the-collection) but by creating a specific function, and have a result from that :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("String"),
"content" : {
    "href" : "String",
    "text" : "String",
    "code" : "String "
}
}
```

to that :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("String"),
"href" : "String",
"text" : "String",
"code" : "String "
}
```

Any suggestions please. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not fancy aggregation (or your `content`'s content may differ across documents) you can also use

```
 db.coll.find().forEach(function (d) {
    db.coll.update({
        _id : d._id
    }, {
        $set : d.content,
        $unset : {
            'content' : 1
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiets way to do it is to use aggregation framework.
Then save output into `newCollection` and after verification you can delete old one and rename created one.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
            $project : {
                _id : 1,    
                href : "$content.href",
                text : "$content.text",
                code : "$content.code",    
            }
        }, {
            $out : "newCollection"
        }
    ])
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but in fact i want to use a spesific function like the previous response. thank you very much.