# Java Spring Boot can't read result from keys whose value is a hashmap

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a simple server reads all logs from mongodb, but some data in the db has different format for their result property.

**one is whose result property has a value like a hashmap:**

```
{
    "event_name" : "Transfer", 
    "result" : { "_from" : "0x928c9af0651632157ef27a2cf17ca72c575a4d21", 
                   "_value" : "1111", 
                 "_to"  :"0x143449e55cdd2a5bae081f041650ba9089812a95" },  

 "transaction_id":"c2c986a96a0cfa7fc96619733449fd88c9d685bf704a50d07baef74f6
}
```

**then for the result property, it returns an empty result for me, 
but if the result property is like this, which is just like an array:**

```
"result" : ["0x928c9af0651632157ef27a2cf17ca72c575a4d21",  "1111", "0x143449e55cdd2a5bae081f041650ba9089812a95"],
```

**then it will outputs the result value.**
**The thing is it has both format in the mongodb, is there any way to handle both of the 2 different format of result property?**

```
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONArray;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

@Document(collection = "eventLog")
public class EventLogEntity implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -70777625567836430L;

  @Id
  private String id;

  @Field(value = "block_number")
  @JsonProperty(value = "block_number")
  private long blockNumber;

  @Field(value = "block_timestamp")
  @JsonProperty(value = "block_timestamp")
  private long blockTimestamp;

  @Field(value = "contract_address")
  @JsonProperty(value = "contract_address")
  private String contractAddress;

  @Field(value = "event_name")
  @JsonProperty(value = "event_name")
  private String entryName;

  @Field(value = "result")
  @JsonProperty(value = "result")
  private JSONArray resultJsonArray;

  @Field(value = "transaction_id")
  @JsonProperty(value = "transaction_id")
  private String transactionId;

  public EventLogEntity(long blockNumber, long blockTimestamp, String contractAddress,
      String entryName, JSONArray resultJsonArray, String transactionId) {
    this.blockNumber = blockNumber;
    this.blockTimestamp = blockTimestamp;
    this.contractAddress = contractAddress;
    this.entryName = entryName;
    this.resultJsonArray = resultJsonArray;
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
  }

  public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
    return serialVersionUID;
  }

  public long getBlockNumber() {
    return blockNumber;
  }

  public void setBlockNumber(long blockNumber) {
    this.blockNumber = blockNumber;
  }

  public long getBlockTimestamp() {
    return blockTimestamp;
  }

  public void setBlockTimestamp(long blockTimestamp) {
    this.blockTimestamp = blockTimestamp;
  }

  public String getContractAddress() {
    return contractAddress;
  }

  public void setContractAddress(String contractAddress) {
    this.contractAddress = contractAddress;
  }

  public String getEntryName() {
    return entryName;
  }

  public void setEntryName(String entryName) {
    this.entryName = entryName;
  }

  public JSONArray getResultJsonArray() {
    System.out.println(resultJsonArray.toString());
    return resultJsonArray;
  }

  public void setResultJsonArray(JSONArray resultJsonArray) {
    this.resultJsonArray = resultJsonArray;
  }

  public String getTransactionId() {
    return transactionId;
  }

  public void setTransactionId(String transactionId) {
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have 2 different documents entities, if you really need keep both formats and read one or other, you should one have Entity for each structure.
One entity will be as you described, and the other will have the result property as follows:

```
public class ResultObject{
   private String _from;
   private String _value;
   private String _to;

   //getters, setters & constructor
}
```

And you reference this ResultObject as property of your other Entity:

```
public class EventLogEntityWithResultObject implements Serializable{
...
private ResultObject result;
...
}
```

If you do not need to keep both structures, you could migrate all documents from one structure type to another using MongoDB commands, see this for example: [Change document structure in mongodb with the mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486849/change-document-structure-in-mongodb-with-the-mongo-shell)

Comment: well, I change the JSONArray type into Object, it works, but just not sure if it is a good idea

Comment: Depends of your needs, if you need to support both type of Entities, it is not bad to separate them into two classes. This is because they have different structure and you should write the code separately to parse it correctly. I strongly think it is bad idea try to have both structures in one Entity. When you have an interface change in your model (i.e Entity), normally you migrate all current data of mongo into the new model structure, that is why I asked if you really need to keep both types of structures

Comment: The thing is the structure varies. Some other enities may have different key value pairs, for examplr, some other data may have result:{ _num: 6, result: 36, id: 334}.